# Asana API querying by assignee_status

Tags: python, asana

When Querying just for tasks that are marked for today in python: 
client.tasks.find_all({ 'assignee_status':'upcoming','workspace': 000000000,'assignee':'me' ,'completed_since':'now'}, page_size=100)

I get a response of all tasks the same as if I would not have included assignee_status
client.tasks.find_all({'workspace': 000000000,'assignee':'me' ,'completed_since':'now'}, page_size=100)

The workspace space has around 5 task that are marked for today.

Thank you,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

You actually can't filter by assignee_status at all - if you pass the parameter it is silently ignored. We could change it so that unrecognized parameters result in errors, which would help make this clearer.

Comment: Thank you, is there any plans to make an option to allow filtering by today / upcoming / later?

Comment: We're hoping to eventually add that feature via more advanced search/sorting/filtering, but it's not in our current near-term roadmap.

Comment: @agnoster  this seems like a very reasonable feature ... not sure why it wasnt included before ... I get the feeling you guys have basically frozen developement of the API(you have a big backlog that you might get to "someday")  I wish I could see more progress on the API it feels like it is simply missing alot of features that should be there (although what is there is well documented) ... the api was one of the main reasons our company picked asana as our project management software.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Obviously we have limited resources and quite a lot of work to do. The good news is that we recently grew the team and are continuing to do so.
We've recently added pagination, external data for OAuth apps, published first-party clients in JS and Python (with more on the way!), completed an overhaul to our developer site and documentation, and launched the new Events API. Development on the API definitely hasn't halted, we're just getting started.

Please contact api-support@asana.com if you would like to speak in more detail about things!